# Kafka consumer reading messages parallel

Tags: apache-kafka

Can we have multiple consumers to consume from a topic to achieve parallel processing in kafka.
My use case is to read messages from a single partition in parallel.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, please indicate what research you've already done, e.g read the kafka documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can process messages in parallel using many Kafka consumers, but no, it's not possible if you only have one partition.

Parallelism in Kafka consuming is defined by the number of partitions, you can easily re-partition your topic at any time to create more partitions.

An example of how process messages in parallel using [rapids-kafka-client](https://github.com/mageddo-projects/rapids-kafka-client) below, a library to make Kafka parallel consuming easier.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  ConsumerConfig.<String, String>builder()
      .prop(KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName())
      .prop(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName())
      .prop(GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "stocks")
      .topics("stock_changed")
      .consumers(7)
      .callback((ctx, record) -> {
        System.out.printf("status=consumed, value=%s%n", record.value());
      })
      .build()
      .consume()
      .waitFor();
}
```

Comment: Confluent's Parallel Consumer (https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) is another solution, similar to Rapids, but with a lot of extra features and is in active development.

Answer (score 0):

Simply saying we can't achieve partition level parallelism for Consumers by default.

But you can try [Akka Streams Kafka (Reactive kafka)](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html#offset-storage-in-kafka). Once go through thsese docs.

Answer (score 0):

The number of partitions define the level of parallelism to read from a kafka topic. But reading is (more or less) only restricted by your network capacities.

A good pattern is to separate reading and processing of messages (one thread per topic-partition for reading and multiple threads for processing this messages).

Comment: yes.This is what currently we are planning to do.But the issue here will be,we can't reprocess the failed messages again while processing

Comment: What do you mean with "we can't reprocess messages again"? Do you mean that processing of message might fail for some reason and you need want to try later?

I can see two possible actions: Turn off the automatic offset commit and do this manually when you have processed a certain batch. Option two: Send this events two a dead letter topic which you consume too.

Comment: The second option seems fine.i will try that.thank you

Comment: Please be careful with this option - I would recommend to add some counter or last processing timestamp to the messages you send to the dead letter topic (just to avoid processing the same message again and again)

Answer (score 0):

You need multiple partitions to do this, or something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC) to sub divide the single partition.

However, it's recommended to have at least 3 partitions and have at least three consumers running in a group, to utilise high availability. You can again use PC to process all these partitions, sub divided by key, in parallel.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).